# Reverse characters of string in subset of 3

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, slice

Let say my string is as:

```
x = 'abcdefghi'
```

I want to reverse it in subsets of 3, so that my output is:

```
x = 'cbafedihg'
```

i.e. 0th index is swapped with 2nd index, 3rd index swapped with 5th, and so on.

Below is my code based on converting the `string` to `list` and swap the elements within the list:

```
string_list = list(x)
for i in range(len(string_list)/3):
    string_list[i*3], string_list[i*3+2] = string_list[i*3+2], string_list[i*3]

''.join(string_list)
# Output: 'cbafedihg'
```

I want to know what will be the most efficient and most pythonic way to  achieve it.

Note: `len(x)%3` will always be 0.

Comment: Added the alternative approaches I could think of as an answer. I am still interested to know if there is any more efficient way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative to achieve this is to type-cast your string to `list`, then simply swap the elements of `list` using *list slicing* with step as 3, and join back the list of strings as:

```
>>> string_list = list(x)
>>> string_list[::3], string_list[2::3] = string_list[2::3], string_list[::3]
>>> ''.join(string_list)
'cbafedihg'
```

Answer (score 5):

The above code can be written using `string slicing` and `list comprehension` as:

```
# Here x[i*3:i*3+3][::-1] will reverse the substring of 3 chars
>>> ''.join([x[i*3:i*3+3][::-1] for i in range(len(x)/3)])
'cbafedihg'
```

Based on the comment by [Delgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291710/delgan), it could be further simplified using `step` as 3 with `range` itself as:

```
>>> ''.join(x[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(x), 3))
'cbafedihg'
```

Comment: Other alternative: `''.join(x[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(x), 3))` This presents the advantage of using generator comprehension instead of list comprehension, this seems more readable to me (less indice multiplications) and this is compatible with Python 3 as no floating division is done.

Comment: @Delgan: Yes, that is also one nice solution. I missed that one. Definitely it is much cleaner compared to the 1st solution I mentioned here.

Comment: @Delgan: Should I add it as edit with my answer, OR you will add it as an answer? Because, I think this will be helpful of the other users visiting SO in the future

Comment: My alternative solution does not deserve its own response, an update of your answer seems to be a good solution. :)

Comment: Updated it. I believe you deserve credit for that, so shared the link of your profile with it. Hope you won't mind :)

Comment: It was not necessary but it is very kind of you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function that is more readable and flexible?

```
def get_string(input_str, step=3):
    output = ""
    i = 0
    for _ in list(input_str):
        if i == len(input_str):
            return output
        elif i+step-1 >= len(input_str):
            output += input[len(input_str)-1:i-1:-1]
            return output
        else:
            output += input_str[i+step-1:i:-1] + input_str[i]
            i += step
    return output
```

And here comes the flexible part:

```
get_string("abcdefghi")
# Ouputs 'cbafedihg'
get_string("abcdefghi", 2)
# Outputs 'badcfehgi'
get_string("abcdefghi", 5)
# Outputs 'edcbaihgf'
```

Not to mention, if you want to add some more logic or change the logic, it is easier to change here.